# Mod rewrite - 301 redirecting despite condition

Tags: apache

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/lib/sub
RewriteRule ^/lib/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Files in /lib/sub are being redirected but the should be exempt from the re-direct.

Comment: Is it htaccess rules or server config rules?

Comment: it is a htaccess rule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
RewriteCond $1 !^sub
RewriteRule ^/?lib/(.*)$ http://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: that has worked for the folder but has affected other folders too.

Comment: @user1209203 your version is probably also work, but without the forward slash in the rule in htaccess context. Can not imagine your conditions and configs.